# Azure DevOps Run Console Application and Write Files

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Here's what I'm trying to achieve;

I have this console application that write some files

```
string src = $"{path}/{filename}.js";
Directory.CreateDirectory(src);
StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(src);
writer.WriteLine("some code");
writer.Dispose();
```

and I'm trying to run the application from Azure DevOps Pipeline:

```
-- Task:
PowerShell Script (console)

-- Script:
cd "$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/publish/"
dotnet .\Console.dll
```

and I'm getting the following error

```
Unhandled exception. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
```

I'm using $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) in attempt to write the files and the path it's correct. But I do not have permission. So, is there a way to write these files inside any other Pipeline directory?

[UPDATE]

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  demands:
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio

variables:
  BuildConfiguration: 'release'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Use Node 16.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 16.x

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
    workingDir: App/Script
    verbose: false

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: build
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: App/Script
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run build'

- task: bleddynrichards.Assembly-Info-Task.Assembly-Info-NetCore.Assembly-Info-NetCore@3
  displayName: 'Set Assembly Manifest Data'
  inputs:
    VersionNumber: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    InformationalVersion: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    PackageVersion: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'

#Task group has not been exported, task groups are not supported yet

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish (console)'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/Console.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/publish'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false

- powershell: |
   cd "$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/publish/"
   
   dotnet .\Console.dll
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script (console)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Agent.TempDirectory)\WebAppContent\Script\build'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: App/Script/build
    Contents: '**\*.js'
    TargetFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)\WebAppContent\Script\build'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Agent.TempDirectory)\WebAppContent\Script\community'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: App/Script/community
    Contents: '**\?(*.css|*.html)'
    TargetFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)\WebAppContent\Script\community'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Agent.TempDirectory)\WebAppContent\wwwroot\preview'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: App/wwwroot/preview
    TargetFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)\WebAppContent\wwwroot\preview'
  enabled: false

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Agent.TempDirectory)\WebAppContent\preview'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: App/wwwroot/preview
    TargetFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)\WebAppContent\preview'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive $(Agent.TempDirectory)\WebAppContent'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)\WebAppContent'
    includeRootFolder: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: Artifact App v2'
  inputs:
    ArtifactName: 'Artifact App v2'
```

```
2023-11-09T20:33:42.3048497Z ##[section]Starting: dotnet publish (console)
2023-11-09T20:33:42.3207943Z ==============================================================================
2023-11-09T20:33:42.3208458Z Task         : .NET Core
2023-11-09T20:33:42.3208576Z Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
2023-11-09T20:33:42.3209305Z Version      : 2.221.0
2023-11-09T20:33:42.3209415Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-11-09T20:33:42.3209593Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
2023-11-09T20:33:42.3210232Z ==============================================================================
2023-11-09T20:33:42.9196083Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
2023-11-09T20:33:42.9322561Z Active code page: 65001
2023-11-09T20:33:42.9384010Z Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
2023-11-09T20:33:44.2850247Z [command]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe publish D:\a\1\s\Console\Console.csproj --configuration release --output D:\a\1\a/publish
2023-11-09T20:33:44.5561473Z MSBuild version 17.7.3+4fca21998 for .NET
2023-11-09T20:33:45.5100268Z   Determining projects to restore...
2023-11-09T20:33:46.1134803Z   All projects are up-to-date for restore.
2023-11-09T20:33:47.5518939Z   *** -> D:\a\1\s\***\bin\release\net7.0\***.dll
2023-11-09T20:33:48.0428117Z   Console -> D:\a\1\s\Console\bin\release\net7.0\Console.dll
2023-11-09T20:33:48.3886070Z   Console -> D:\a\1\a\publish\
2023-11-09T20:33:48.4493919Z Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version which are currently lts. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 5.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. You can learn more about the breaking changes here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/ and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/ . To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
2023-11-09T20:33:48.4567266Z ##[section]Finishing: dotnet publish (console)
```

```
2023-11-09T20:33:48.4603595Z ##[section]Starting: PowerShell Script (console)
2023-11-09T20:33:48.4786198Z ==============================================================================
2023-11-09T20:33:48.4786505Z Task         : PowerShell
2023-11-09T20:33:48.4786620Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
2023-11-09T20:33:48.4787077Z Version      : 2.231.0
2023-11-09T20:33:48.4787187Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-11-09T20:33:48.4787341Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
2023-11-09T20:33:48.4787703Z ==============================================================================
2023-11-09T20:33:49.6422589Z Generating script.
2023-11-09T20:33:49.7011882Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2023-11-09T20:33:49.7226740Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\cc709fd9-46e0-4d66-9c8b-6b3330ff72c4.ps1'"
2023-11-09T20:33:50.6689651Z APP_ROOT_PATH: D:\a\1\s
2023-11-09T20:33:50.6897634Z Unhandled exception. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\a\1\s\***\wwwroot\build\***.js' is denied.
2023-11-09T20:33:50.6921080Z    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.CreateFile(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
2023-11-09T20:33:50.6968446Z    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)
2023-11-09T20:33:50.6999702Z    at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)
2023-11-09T20:33:50.7041688Z    at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategyCore(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)
2023-11-09T20:33:50.7087362Z    at System.IO.StreamWriter.ValidateArgsAndOpenPath(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
2023-11-09T20:33:50.7185463Z    at System.IO.File.AppendText(String path)
2023-11-09T20:33:50.7212481Z    at Console.Program.***(ISettings settings, IQueryCollection queryParams, String format) in D:\a\1\s\Console\Program.cs:line 55
2023-11-09T20:33:50.7249512Z    at Console.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\a\1\s\Console\Program.cs:line 37
2023-11-09T20:33:53.4052277Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2023-11-09T20:33:53.4379907Z ##[section]Finishing: PowerShell Script (console)
```

Comment: Please check if this directory exists. build.ArtifactStagingDirectory is used to copy artifacts. If you are not on the deployment job that downloaded artifacts, there's a chance that this directory doesn't exist. Please check instead Build.SourcesDirectory/publish/. Ideally, it would be best if you shared the entire pipeline.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej see if the update helps

Comment: Are these separate jobs or pipelines?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej tasks in a single pipeline

Comment: But on one pipeline you can have several jobs. I feel you are missing important aspects here. Could you post whole pipeline?

Comment: Agree with @KrzysztofMadej. Notice there are 2 `steps`  for the tasks, which is used in `2`  jobs. If so, to transfer the data, you could need to publish the artifact and download it in your 2nd job.  In addition, in you PowerShell task log, there is `APP_ROOT_PATH: D:\a\1\s` appended which cannot be found in your PowerShell script. It's recommended to share your complete yaml to avoid the confusion.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej I am using one pipeline with multiple jobs. Check the update.

Comment: @Pablo, may i know if there's any update? Please check my sample below and let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the yaml content, you are using `one job` but not multiple jobs.

In your powershell script, you cd into the artifact publish folder, but the dotnet command invoke the js file in your source directory `D:\a\1\s\...`. I followed your script and it's working on my side.

I set the file path as below:
[image]

My yaml for your reference, i added a new powershell task to check the js file in D:\a\1\s.

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '6.x'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish (console)'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/ConsoleApp1.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/publish'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false

- powershell: |
   Get-Childitem –Path . -Recurse
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script (console)'

- powershell: |
   cd "$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/publish/"

   Get-Childitem –Path . -Recurse
   dotnet .\ConsoleApp1.dll
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script (console)'
```

[image]

Please check the path in cs file, and add powershell task as above to check the js file before your dotnet command, confirm it's generated.

Answer (score 0):

Each job is executed on separate machine. This is why ii you create artifact is not available on the other job. To make it available you need to use [publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) step in first job and then download on second. If your second job is deployment job then artifact is downloaded automatically.

Publish step

```
steps:
- publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/bin/WebApp
  artifact: WebApp
```

And then in second job

```
steps:
- download: current
  artifact: WebApp
```

Also make sure you use proper directory when you run app

> By default, files are downloaded to $(Pipeline.Workspace). If an artifact name was not specified, a subdirectory will be created for each downloaded artifact. You can use matching patterns to limit which files get downloaded.